# Is there solid evidence, that antibiotics cause allergies?

Tags: allergy, antibiotics

I have read, that the use of antibiotics could be part of the reason for the increase in allergies, we see today.

In alternative medicine circles, it is a common theme to reduce the use of antibiotics as much as possible and only use them, when it is absolutely necessary. This is done for a variety of reasons.

However, with traditional medicine, antibiotics, especially for children are prescribed more liberally, with the intention to err on the safe side. GPs generally follow well-established practices and don't consider arguments for or against something, unless they are widely accepted.

So I wonder what is the case with the claim, that antibiotics cause allergies: Is there solid data behind it, which is too new to reach the GPs or is it a claim with not sufficient data backing it?

Comment: If you're talking about the increase in allergies in the population, rather than in an individual, then it is almost impossible to know.  There are a lot of theories but they are essentially unable to be proven because of the inability to differentiate between potential etiologies.

Comment: `In alternative medicine circles, it is a common theme to reduce the use of antibiotics as much as possible and only use them, when it is absolutely necessary.` -- Actually, that's a common theme in conventional medicine as well in the modern world.

Comment: No, this is just how it should be. In practice anti-biotics are routinely over-prescribed without tests, just to be on the safe side in all countries.

Answer (score 6):

The possible link between antibiotics and increased allergy and asthma incidence was mentioned at the 2004 annual meeting of American Society for Microbiology [(New Scientist, 2004)](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn5047-antibiotics-linked-to-huge-rise-in-allergies/). They said that increased antibiotic use may change normal intestinal flora; more exactly, it may stimulate yeast overgrowth, which may then alter the immunity, but they didn't say how.

In [a 2013 systematic review of observational studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23782060), there was a significant dose-response association, suggesting a 7% increase in the risk of eczema for each additional antibiotic course received during the first year of life.

In [a 2016 case-control study by South Carolina University](https://aacijournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13223-016-0148-7), using data from 2007 to 2009, the use of systemic antibiotics in 1504 infants was associated by increased risk (ratio: 1.21-1.64) of food allergies later in life.

In [a cohort study published in JAMA Pediatrics in 2018](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamapediatrics/article-abstract/2676167), the use of antibiotics in 131708 children in their first 6 months of life was associated with an increase (ratio: 1.14-2.09) in allergies (asthma, allergic rhinitis, anaphylaxis, allergic conjunctivitis) later in life.

The mentioned studies were not randomized controlled clinical trials, so the question how solid this evidence is still remains unanswered.